Snowflake query to aggregate data using pivot values
I have the following table with array values in rows which needs to be aggregated using different timestamp level in snowflake



Bill_id
BillStarttime
Bill_Submitted
Billpaid
Billpaidtime
Bill_main_item
Bill_sub




1
2024-09-18T10:00
1
1
2024-09-19T11:00
Iron
[Cast,Ore]


2
2024-09-18T11:00
1
1
2024-09-19T12:00
Steel
[Cast,Alloy]


3
2024-09-18T19:00
1
1
2024-09-19T12:00
Iron
[Cast,Ore]


4
2024-09-19T19:00
1
0
2024-09-19T10:00
Iron
[Cast,Ore,Aly]


5
2024-09-19T15:00
1
1
2024-09-19T10:00
Steel
[cast]



Now I want to aggregate the data like below
for 18th based on billstart_time the total bill submitted for Iron (mainitem), Cast, ore (Bill sub) is 2 and bill paid for 18th is for Iron, Cast, ore is 0 as there is no bill paid for 18th.
So based on each bill_main_item and splitting of array in bill sub we have to aggregate the count of bill_submitted by bill_start_time and bill paid by bill paid time.

Please update your question to show 1) the result you want to achieve, based on your source data 2) the SQL you’ve managed to wrote so far. All as editable text, appropriately formatted

(bill paid for 18th is for Iron, Cast, [Ore] is 0 as there is no bill paid for 18th (ignoring confusing grammar,) did you intend 19th in this half-sentence?)

What is your answerable programming question about all this?
